# How to add a CKeditor Addon?

Tags: wysiwyg

What's is the correct way to add a CKeditor Addon?

Like this one: http://ckeditor.com/addon/fontawesome

**Where should the plugin be located?**

```
sites/all/modules/ckeditor/plugins 

or

site/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins
```

**Some plugins need some configuration in the js,**

```
Should I change ckeditor/config.js

or

should be added in "Custom JavaScript configuration" in admin page
```

I guess I can not use the CKBuilder. Can I?